A property of $\lt$ in Primitive recursive arithmetic
In Primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA), we can introduce $\lt$ by introducing its representing function $K_{\lt}$, where $K_{\lt}(x,y) =sg(x+1-y)$. Here "sg" and "-" are the functions defined by $sg(0)=0\land sg(x+1)=1$,  $pred(0)=0\land pred(x+1)=x$ and $a-0=a\land  a-(b+1)=pred(a-b)$.
In this situation, I want to prove in PRA that if $K_{\lt}(x,y+1)=0$, then $K_{\lt}(x,y)=0\lor x=y$.
If $K_{\lt}(x,y+1)=0$, then $sg( (x+1)-(y+1))=sg(pred(x+1-y))=0$. Note that by the induction axiom $sg(x)=0\to x=0$ and $pred(x)=0\to x=0\lor x=1$. Hence we have $x+1-y=0\lor x+1-y=1$. If $x+1-y=0$, then $sg(x+1-y)=0$, so $K_{\lt}(x,y)=0$.
But, I do not know how to prove in PRA with those recursive defining equations that if $x+1-y=1$, then $x=y$. Is is necessary to adopt this as a new axiom?
I konw that PRA is strong enough to prove the Gödel incompleteness theorems and many other logical consequnces, and these logical results are proved by introducing new primitive recursive functions with those recursive defining equations. In this point, I want to know whether those recursive defining equations are strong enough to deduce basic properties like "if $x+1-y=1$, then $x=y$".

Keep working on the proof that if $x + 1 - y = 1$, then $x = y$. Try a few special cases first: e.g., $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. Try to build a proof up from simpler lemmas. If you continue to have problems, let us know what you have tried.

thank you for the comment. I have proved it when $x=0$ or $y=0$. But I couldn't have the full proof. My attempt was using the induction axiom and those special cases, but I have no idea.

Working in PRA is always difficult. The early definitions work right out of the box but everyone who tries to work through it from scratch soon runs into a wall. Fortunately, R. L. Goodstein persisted through the endeavor and wrote a book about it:
Goodstein, R. L., Recursive number theory. A development of recursive arithmetic in a logic-free equation calculus, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics. Amsterdam: North-Holland Publishing Company XII, 190 p. (1957). ZBL0077.01401.
I learned so many great tricks reading this book and I always look back at it when I forget one.
As you read the book, you will see that Goodstein spends a great deal of effort at the beginning to prove that diagonal recursion is valid:
Given $a \in \mathbb{N}$, and primitive recursive $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $h:\mathbb{N}^3\to\mathbb{N}$ the function $k:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}$ is primitive recursive, where $k$ is defined by the equations:
$$\begin{aligned}
k(0,0) &= a \\
k(x+1, 0) &= f(x) \\
k(0, y+1) &= g(y) \\
k(x+1, y+1) &= h(k(x,y),x,y)
\end{aligned}$$
This is not exactly how Goodstein stated it but it is basically the same. Once you have this fact, statements like yours are much easier to prove!

Thank you so much! If we define the $\lt$-representing function $K_{\lt}$ by using that diagonal recursion, then statements like "$K_{\lt}(x,y+1)=0$ implies $K_{\lt}(x,y)=0\lor x=y$" are easily provable. Is this your argument?

Yes, of course. But my main argument is to read Goodstein's book!
